# WPF Listbox alternating rows and move up /down functionality

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, listbox

I am working on WPF Listbox with alternating color rows(First row white color and second Gray color) and move up/down rows functionality.Both have been achieved but when I move second row up to first position the background changes to Gray color.Similarly if the first color is gray after moving up the position from second row the background color again changes to white color by clicking move down button.This behavior not observable on rows number above 2.If I move position 3 and 4 up/down only row content move up and down the background color remains fixed.I am not able to find reason for this strange behavior.Any help would be appreciated.

Code Snippet of XAML

```
<Style x:Key="AlternatingListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CollectioNames}" x:Name="listBox"  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource AlternatingListViewItemStyle}"  AlternationCount="2"  SelectionMode="Multiple" >

                <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <Grid Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition  Width="200*" MinWidth="200" ></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition  Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition  Width="Auto"  ></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="checkBoxList" Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Path=Item.Name}"  />

                            <Button x:Name="btnListUp"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Click="moveUp_Click"  Content="Ç"  FontFamily="Wingdings 3"   VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                            <Button x:Name="btnListDown"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Click="moveDown_Click" FontFamily="Wingdings 3" Content="È"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"   />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Code behind Code

```
public ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<MyClass>> CollectioNames { get; set; }

 private void moveUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                Button button = sender as Button;
                var dataContext = button.DataContext;

                CheckedListItem<MyClass> selectedfile = button.DataContext as CheckedListItem<MyClass>;

                int index = CollectioNames.IndexOf(selectedfile);
                if (index > 0)
                {
                    CollectioNames.Move(index, index - 1);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

        private void moveDown_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Button button = sender as Button;
                var dataContext = button.DataContext;

                CheckedListItem<MyClass> selectedfile = button.DataContext as CheckedListItem<MyClass>;

                int index = CollectioNames.IndexOf(selectedfile);
                if (index < CollectioNames.Count - 1)
                {
                    CollectioNames.Move(index, index + 1);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: Eeww, you should really consider using mvvm... Anyway this behaviour makes perfect sense...

Comment: Could you elaborate a littel bit?